# Basic ceasar cipher

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, counter, caesar-cipher

Write a program that will implement a “shift right by 5” Caesar Cipher Machine.  The letters will be entered one character at a time.  The program will terminate when an empty input is encountered.

My code

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
key = "fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcde"
n=input("Enter a letter: ")
message=""
for letter in n:
    if letter.lower() in alphabet:
        message += key[alphabet.find(letter.lower())]
    else:
        message += letter
print(message)
```

I'm fairly new to python and I am having trouble with my code. I want if the user entered nothing when prompt, it will print everything he entered as encrypted key. Also as stated in the question, it should ask for the user multiple inputs and it will only end once the user did not input anything when asked.

Cheers to everyone!

Example 
Enter a letter: a
Enter a letter: b
Enter a letter: c
Enter a letter: (empty, enter)

f g h

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that if the user answers something not in the alphabet, you just want that to stay the same (periods, etc.)

Your problem can be solved quite simply with while loops. All you need is to keep going until n is not a blank space:

```
while n != "":
    for letter in n:
        if letter.lower() in alphabet:
            message += key[alphabet.find(letter.lower())]
        else:
            message += letter
```

The loop will run until the user has entered a blank space.